# I'm getting an error in C programming. ([Error] expected identifier or '(' before '{' token) .Can someone please help me out and let me know why?

Tags: c, recursion, compiler-errors, function-definition

//Ackermann function using Recursion

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int ack(int,int);
    int main(void)
    {
        int m,n;
        printf("Enter values for m and n:\t");
        scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
        printf("The answer is %d\t",ack(m,n));
        return 0;
    }
     int ack(int m,int n);


     {

        if(m==0)
          return n+1;
        else if(m>0&&n==0)
          return ack(m-1,1);
        else if (m>0 && n>0);
          return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
     }
```

//[Error]- expected identifier or '(' before '{' token)

Comment: `int ack(int m,int n);` shouldn't end with a semicolon.

Comment: As William Pursell points out in the answer the problem is a superfluous semicolon. It causes a function header to become a forward declaration, so the function's body below it is orphaned, hence the error of an unexpected token `{`.

Comment: You should have carefully read the error message – it points at the line number where the error occured, and that should help you understand what the message is about.

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semi-colon that needs to be removed.

The forward declaration of `ack` requires the semi-colon, but when you are defining the function there can not be a semi-colon between the parameter list and the `{`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int ack(int,int);
int main(void)
{
    int m,n;
    printf("Enter values for m and n:\t");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    printf("The answer is %d\t",ack(m,n));
    return 0;
}
 int ack(int m,int n);   /* <------   REMOVE THIS SEMI-COLON */


 {

    if(m==0)
      return n+1;
    else if(m>0&&n==0)
      return ack(m-1,1);
    else if (m>0 && n>0);  /* <--- Also (probably) here */
      return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
 }
```

The second semi-colon mentioned in my comments above is not a syntax error, and removing it will change the semantics.  Indeed, in this case removing it will probably lead to a compiler warning about a missing return.  However, that semi-colon is extremely misleading to anyone reading the code and ought to be removed just for the sake of readability.  If that is indeed the semantics you want, you should put it on a line by itself and remove a level of indentation from the return that follows it.

Answer (score 1):

You placed semicolons in two different places in the program by mistake.

The first one is

```
 int ack(int m,int n);
                   ^^^^

 {
     //...
```

The second one is

```
else if (m>0 && n>0);
                   ^^^^
      return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
```

As far as I know thr function is defined for unsigned (non-negative) integers.

It can be defined the following way

```
unsigned long long int ackermann( unsigned long long int m, unsigned long long int n )
{
    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n + 1;
    }
    else if (n == 0)
    {
        return ackermann( m - 1, 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        return ackermann( m - 1, ackermann( m, n - 1 ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just remove comma after else if statement and after function definition

```
#include<stdio.h>

int ack(int,int);

int main(void)
{
    int m,n;
    printf("Enter values for m and n:\t");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    printf("The answer is %d\t",ack(m,n));
    return 0;
}
 int ack(int m,int n)
 {

    if(m==0)
      return n+1;
    else if(m>0&&n==0)
      return ack(m-1,1);
    else if (m>0 && n>0)
      return ack(m-1,ack(m,n-1));
 }
```

Comment: Comma and semicolon are two entirely different things.